# Kali Linux openVPN does not pass the DNS Leak test

Tags: linux, dns, vpn, kali-linux, openvpn

I recently installed Kali Linux on VMWare. I was able to successfully install openVPN following [these](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/03/01/setup-vpn-on-kali-linux/4/) instructions, but it seems that it does not pass the [DNS Leak test](http://dnsleak.com/). Is there anything that can fix that?

Also, how can I stop my internet connection if my VPN fails? I do not want to expose my real IP.

Comment: What is the "DNS test"?

Comment: I tried the DNS Leak test, check here: http://dnsleak.com/

Comment: In addition to @ysdx
[man openvpn](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html) is always a good place to start. Write a config file too so you can just run `openvpn conf.ovpn` as root. Basically you want to use the `--route-up cmd`, `--up cmd`, `--down-pre cmd`, etc to run custom scripts, and `--route network/IP [netmask] [gateway] [metric]` which will tear down the routes automatically in reverse order  when the conn closes.

All these cmd-line directives can be put  in  a config file also once it works. Sounds like your not routing properly.

Comment: Also, you can use `iptables` to block all egress traffic except destined to you VPN provider or proxy. If your really paranoid, you can try connecting to your VPN from behind a whonix vm. The VPN must be TCP, and it would probably be best to do it from within a VM with Kali configured as a workstation for the whonix gateway. Don't expect any solution to protect you against the NSA or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

By default, OpenVPN does not reconfigure the DNS on non-Windows. You could use a [hook](https://wiki.ldn-fai.net/wiki/Tuto_Client_OpenVPN) (sorry the explanations are in French) in order to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Write foreign options to stdout:
foreign_options() {
   local i
   while true; do
       local varname=foreign_option_$i
       local value="$(eval echo \$$varname)"
       if [ -z "$value" ]; then
           return
       fi
       i=$((i+1))
   done
}

# Get resolvconf configuration:
create_resolvconf() {
   foreign_options | grep "^dhcp-option DNS " | sed "s/^dhcp-option DNS /nameserver /"
}

route_up() {
   # Append nameservers to resolvconf (it would be better to override them):
   create_resolvconf | resolvconf -a $rdev
}

route_pre_down() {
   # Kill switch (adjust with your real network interface):
   sudo ip link set eth0 up
   # Restore the DNS config:
   resolvconf -d $rdev
}

case "$script_type" in
   route-up) route_up "$@" ;;
   pre_down) route_pre_down "$@" ;;
esac
```

With this OpenVPN configuration snippet:

```
script-security 2
down my_script
route-pre-down my_script
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working, please make sure you firstly:

1) Sort out DNS nameservers

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and change it so you have

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

2) Download OpenVPN configurations from [VPNBook](http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn) and extract them somewhere.

3) In Iceweasel/Firefox type in the URL bar:

```
about:config
```

it will ask you to 'be careful'

4) Search for 'media.peerconnection.enabled' and make sure it is set to false by double clicking it.

5) Close your browser

6) Change directory in terminal to where you have extracted OpenVPN config files.

7) Use the `openvpn` command to load the VPN and enter in the username and password.

8) Once it has initialized go to your browser and check dnsleaktest

Answer (score -1):

You should try to configure your proxychains

Edit `/etc/proxychains.conf`: 
change it to `dynamic`, and add `socks5 127.0.0.1 9050` after socks4.

use in a terminal:
`~$ proxychains iceweasel www.dnsleaktest.com`